# Execute PowerShell command from VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, iis-8.5

I have a PowerShell command which removes virtual Folder from the IIS (8.5)

```bsh
Remove-Item IIS:\Sites\WebsiteName\VirtualFolderName -Force -Recurse
```

This works just fine when executed standalone from PowerShell console, but I want to run this from inside of a VBScript. I have VBScript something like this:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -Command='Remove-Item IIS:\Sites\WebsiteName\VirtualFolderName -Force -Recurse'")
```

When I execute above it wont work, and it just spits out the command on the PowerShell console.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes only work inside PowerShell. You need double quotes around the PowerShell statement, and you must double them to escape them inside the VBScript string. Also, remove the `=` between the parameter `-Command` and its argument. If the module `WebAdministration` isn't loaded automatically you need to do it yourself, otherwise you won't have a drive `IIS:`.

Change this:

```vb
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -Command='Remove-Item IIS:\Sites\WebsiteName\VirtualFolderName -Force -Recurse'")
```

into this:

```vb
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -Command ""Import-Module WebAdministration; Remove-Item IIS:\Sites\WebsiteName\VirtualFolderName -Force -Recurse""")
```

Comment: got error :
Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.

Comment: @Pankaj Load the module `WebAdministration`. See updated answer.